# Is there a way to import the contents of am sql file in AWS SAM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-athena, aws-sam

I'm developing a proyect using AWS SAM. In this proyect, I use **state functions** to execute Athena queries and process the results with a Lambda. Currently, the athena queries are created as NamedQueries through the aws console (web browser), but given recent events with my team, those saved queries were deleted and now I'm looking for a way to save the queries in the SAM proyect itself so if the queries are ever deleted, I can restore them through the CloudFormation stack.

My approach is to create the named queries in the template as such:

```yaml
Resources:
  Type: AWS::Athena::NamedQuery
  Properties: 
    Database: database-name
    Description: Saved query for Step Function
    Name: StepFunctionQueryName
    QueryString:
    SELECT t.column_a, ot.column_b FROM database-name.table t
    LEFT JOIN database-name.other_table ot ON t.column_a = ot.column_a
    WHERE ot.column_b IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY ot.column_b
    WorkGroup: primary
```

This works just fine. However, the actual `QueryString` is too large and makes the `template.yaml` file harder to read. And since I'm using multiple queries in the same proyect, this template gets bigger and bigger.

Is there a way to save the query strings in a separate file like `QueryA.sql` and reference its contents in the template? Something like this:

```yaml
Resources:
  Type: AWS::Athena::NamedQuery
  Properties: 
    Database: database-name
    Description: Saved query for Step Function
    Name: StepFunctionQueryName
    QueryString: !File ./queries/QueryA.sql
    WorkGroup: primary
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can import the contents of an SQL file in AWS SAM (Serverless Application Model) by utilizing AWS services like AWS Lambda and Amazon RDS (Relational Database Service). Here's an overview of the steps involved:

1. Create an AWS Lambda function: Set up an AWS Lambda function using AWS SAM to handle the import process. You can write your function code in a language supported by AWS Lambda, such as Python or Node.js.
2. Connect to the Amazon RDS database: Establish a connection from your Lambda function to the Amazon RDS database instance where you want to import the SQL file. Ensure that your Lambda function has the necessary permissions to access the database.
3. Read the SQL file: Within your Lambda function, use file handling techniques to read the SQL file's contents. You can use libraries like fs in Node.js or open the file in Python to retrieve the SQL statements.
4. Execute SQL statements: Execute the SQL statements obtained from the file using appropriate database client libraries or drivers within your Lambda function. You can execute the statements one by one or as a batch, depending on your requirements.
5. Trigger the Lambda function: Configure an event trigger to invoke the Lambda function when the import operation is required. For example, you can use an AWS CloudWatch Event or manually invoke the Lambda function through the AWS Management Console or AWS CLI.
6. Test and monitor: Test the Lambda function by triggering it with sample SQL files and monitor the execution logs for any errors or issues. Make any necessary adjustments to handle errors gracefully and ensure the import process completes successfully.

By following these steps, you can import the contents of an SQL file into your Amazon RDS database using AWS SAM and Lambda. Remember to consider security, error handling, and performance optimizations specific to your use case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Tanay ! The solution you're proposing is not to use the sql content in the AWS SAM template, but to run them in a Lambda. This is doable but I'd like to see if there's a way for the resource to be specified in the template before I attempt your proposed solution